Setting MariaDB encryption
Hello I need to Configure a MariaDB server to provide data encryption during storage. I am performing the task on linux oracle 9. when I try to restart the server, I get the following message
[vagrant@localhost mysql]$ sudo systemctl restart mariadb
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xeu mariadb.service" for details.
my conf file:
\#
\# This group is read both both by the client and the server
\# use it for options that affect everything
\#
\[client-server\]
\#
\# include all files from the config directory
\[mysqld\]
datadir=/vagrant/db
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.soc
\# File Key Management
plugin_load_add = file_key_management
file_key_management_filename = /etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.enc
file_key_management_filekey = FILE:/etc/mysql/encryption/keyfile.key
file_key_management_encryption_algorithm = AES_CTR
\# InnoDB Encryption
innodb_encrypt_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_temporary_tables = ON
innodb_encrypt_log = ON
innodb_encryption_threads = 4
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age = 1
\[client\]
port=3300
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

ps. If you encrypt everything except the path(datadir=/var/lib/mysql/
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.soc) and port(port=3306), everything works
version mariadb 10.5.22
I tried to change the config, install the plugin plugin_load_add = file_key_management (failed), tried to find the error in /lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service but did not find anything

I would expect that neither client or server will start due to leading backslashes in your configuration file.

I will assume the leading backslashes are just a formatting issue here on SE. To get a better idea of why it's failing, you should take a look at the MariaDB error log. As it doesn't seem to be defined in your conf file (although it could be defined within /etc/my.cnf.d), it should be written to its default location which is your datadir.
